# JSP servlet not executing doPost method

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have recently started programming in java and have been trying out some JSP development. I am trying to make a login page which uses the POST method to transfer data to the servlet. Here is my code:

```
<form method="POST" name ="loginForm"  action="userAuth">
            <input type="hidden" name="userAction" value="login">
            Username: <input type="text" name="txtUsername"> <br>
            Password    : <input type="password" name="txtPassword">
            <br><input type="submit"  value="Login">

</form>
```

The above code is from the initial login page.

The code below is from the userAuth.java file.

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
    String userAction = request.getParameter("userAction");
    if (userAction.equals("Login")) {
    String userName = request.getParameter("txtUsername");
    String passWord = request.getParameter("txtPassword");

    if (userName.equals("hello") && passWord.equals("hello")) {
    response.sendRedirect("Homepage.jsp");
    }
    }
}
```

The problem I have is that when I input the correct username and password, the doPost method is not executed, so none of the redirects take place. Rather only the ProcessRequest method is executed which just displays the initial template to the web browser.

Thank you in advance.

P.S I am using Apache Tomcat 8.0.27.0

Comment: Could you add more information, like how are you deploying jsp (Weblogic, Tomcat....), etc? May be try first with doGet to ensure that the environment is OK.

Comment: @pianista I have tried doGet with no luck.

Comment: Put `@Override` above, so as to check that you have built in all in the correct way. Then check the web.xml or the alternative annotations to map the URL "userAuth" to the correct servlet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved the issue...

The issue was with the following line

```
<input type="hidden" name="userAction" value="**login**">
```

and the subsequent processing in the second block:

```
if (userAction.equals("**Login**")) {}
```

The login value didnt have an uppercase L.

Just changed this.

Answer (score 0):

What does the processRequest() method do? If executes as you say then the server gives a response to the client and the remaining block of code does not execute. Have you tried to run without this function?

Comment: Yes I have tried running without the function, however, I am redirected to the userAuth.java servlet and left there. The doPost isn't executed. And the processRequest() doesn't do anything but output some text to the browser.

Comment: Have you checked your server in debug mode to see if doPost() executes? if yes and you are totally sure it does not maybe there is some mistake in the servlet mappings. Do you use web.xml or annotations?
Does processRequest() execute? IIt is not clear to me.

Comment: Try
RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("Homepage.jsp");

rd.forward(request, response);

Or 

response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "Homepage.jsp");

Answer (score 0):

Hide the process request method.

Like this:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    //processRequest(request, response);
    String userAction = request.getParameter("userAction");
    if (userAction.equals("Login")) {
        String userName = request.getParameter("txtUsername");
        String passWord = request.getParameter("txtPassword");
    }
}
```